# How could I easily tell an Android from a human?

Tags: robots, android

Let’s say Im in a gameshow where I’m stuck in a room with an Android for 10 minutes and I must guess if there an Android or a human. The Android looks all but identical to a human. There a few subtle differences, but I don’t want to embarrass myself in front of tens of millions of viewers. What would be the easiest way to tell an Android from a human?

Edit: The Android is sentient and is also playing the game, albeit casually. Also, the Android was not made specifically to trick humans. Also also, There’s nothing in the room except two chairs and your not allowed to bring anything with you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136590/discussion-on-question-by-icreamforicescream-how-could-i-easily-tell-an-android).

Answer (score 2):

### How to tell an Android from a Human

**1. Motion**

Motion is a big one. Human motions and musculature are very difficult to replicate in mechanical form. Even very good replication of motion is not perfect. This would be especially true of thin and rapid muscles like eyelids, or muscles that are not highly dependent of bone structures like the lips and the tongue.

**2. Style of Thinking, a Modified Turing Test**

Our current type of AI uses extensive data-sets to create plausible speech and other creative tasks. Diverge too far from the data-sets and things start getting messy. Androids often attempt tasks that they shouldn't, so they may end up making strange linguistic constructions and having conversations that make little sense far faster than you can get a human counterpart to. The hard part is to determine which types of questions and linguistic constructions throw them off base the most, and what type of results will be an indicator of non-human stumbling for an answer rather than human stumbling for an answer.

**3. Multi-Spectral Photography**

Materials made to look like human skin may not look that way under another electromagnetic spectrum. Technically, this would probably be cheating, so let's hope that the judges don't notice the custom-made contact lenses that allow you to detect the material differences in the android skin.

**4. Special Rules for Androids**

This is where it gets highly specific to your worldbuilding. You have to ask yourself what limitations or special abilities that androids have that humans don't in your world. Is there a program that is common in some models of androids that will cause them to give away their secret of not being human? Perhaps a testing or debug mode, as is common in some engineered robotic systems.

**5. Special Look or Style**

Perhaps the androids have a particular look or style that is common as well. Something like green eyes could be a feature that is more common in androids than humans, for instance. Or maybe they tend to have straight hair, since protein extrusion that produces curls would jam in the device more often. Maybe they tend to wear a certain brand of clothing, because the robotics company and the clothing company has a partnership. Many of these alone may only amount to a guess, but enough appearance cues could give away the nature of the robot. Again, this would be highly specific to your worldbuilding.

Comment: Did the OP edit his question after you answered? because you spend time on methods that are specifically prohibited by the scenario outlined, no special equipment in the room.

Comment: @Pelinore Yes OP did the edit right after I finished the answer. I've not gone through and fixed the answer as of yet to apply completely.

Comment: @Pelinore Take notice that I did say that the contacts would be a way of cheating, though. They are specifically prohibited, but if the character wants to take a risk (assuming that this is the type of character to do so) then it may happen without notice. Since this is worldbuilding I make no assumptions that the character is honest. This is why I didn't edit it out.

Answer (score 2):

## Exam Time!

This should actually be quite easy if the android wasn't specifically made to fool humans.

- **Check for a pulse**: An android would have no reason to have a pulse.
- **Squeeze a finger**: Does the tissue change color as blood is forced out?
- **Check for breath**: Even if an android can fake a chest inflating, there would be no air moving in and out.
- **Smell**: People stink like people. androids will smell android-like (if that's a thing) or like nothing. Okay, maybe perfume.
- **Imperfections**: Depending on how thorogh the job is, androids might have no flaws in their skin, boogers in their noses, chips in their teeth, or irregular nails.
- **Bite**: Okay, this depends on the rules of the game, and good etiquette. Do they bleed? Do you taste blood? is the tissue the right consistency (if you never bit anyone before, the last part might be tricky...)?

Comment: Androids smell like "new car," for the same reasons that new cars do.

Comment: @Tom Ha! I knew it!

Answer (score 1):

Humans are not perfectly symmetrical. One ear or eye might be slightly lower than the other one. One eye might be slightly more open or closed than the other one. Sometimes a smile is not perfectly symmetrical.

For ease of manufacture, androids would most likely be symmetrical. Check for facial and other symmetries, including finger prints.

If the android has the appearance of a male, does it grow stubble on its face? Check for facial hair.

Answer (score 1):

" Also, the Android was not made specifically to trick humans."

If this is truly the case, then the eyes are a dead (pun intended) giveaway. Specifically, the pupils. There would be no reason for android eyes to dilate because of emotional scenarios. Tell a joke, insult it, embarrass it, strip in front of it. Humans will always show some pupil response to these situations.

Another trick is to try and make it blush.